# 2nd line in li start under the icon after CSS-reset

Tags: css, html

[image: I want to display text as I show in image, but I have used icons before list text , not a bullet point.]

I want to display list items like this

this is how my code display
[image: my code]

I want to start text "server locations" exact under Successful text. How to do this with the help of css?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried/some code.

Comment: I have tried  list-style-position: outside; for ul li. but its not worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this one

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  position:relative;
  padding-left:10px;
}
ul li span.glyphicon{
  position:absolute;
  left:-15px;
  top:4px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record techico" aria-hidden="true"></span>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record techico" aria-hidden="true"></span>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record techico" aria-hidden="true"></span>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record techico" aria-hidden="true"></span>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `list-style: outside;` for list

```css
li {
  list-style: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>

  <li>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
</ul>
```

---

Since you are using custom bulletins, than it means you must move your element outside container.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
li:before {
  content: '->';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>

  <li>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but I used bootstrap galyphicons component in li tag. I dont want li before and after. this is my code: <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record techico" aria-hidden="true"></span>my text</li>

Comment: @sujatak So move my `:before` code to `li .glyphicon`

Comment: but i dont want to use content. that glyphicon has its own icon. you can see that in my question red bullet point in circle.

Comment: @sujatak You have to adapt that code. `content` is for `:after`, don't want it - don't use it...

Answer (score 0):

Check with `glyphicon-record` updates , i have used `glyphicon` as background , try width demo

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  color: red;
  content:"\e165";
  font-family:"Glyphicons Halflings";
  line-height:1;
  left: -20px;
  display:inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>

  <li>Donec purus lectus, tempus at mollis at, volutpat id neque. Aenean id porta metus. Proin blandit rhoncus elementum. Quisque non arcu faucibus, eleifend ex luctus, rhoncus orci. Sed rutrum eros quis accumsan consectetur. Nunc gravida ipsum at pharetra
    dapibus. Cras ornare mauris enim, et pharetra lectus vehicula et.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style: none; /* Remove list bullets */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li { 
    padding-left: 16px; 
}

li:before {
    content: "•"; /* Insert content that looks like bullets */
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: blue; /* Or a color you prefer */
}
</style>
```